# Функции MAX() и MIN() возвращают неправильные значения

Tags: php, sql, max, min

Делаю запрос

```
 $max_crossbar= $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT MAX(crossbar) AS crossbar FROM `alu_user_sport`");
$min_crossbar= $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT MIN(crossbar) AS crossbar FROM `alu_user_sport`");
```

MIN выводит

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [crossbar] => 123 ) )
```

MAX выводит

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [crossbar] => 53 ) )
```

Хотя в базе min и max другие значения
[image: такая же проблема по полю 'incline']
Из за чего такое происходит?

Comment: А тип поля `crossbar` какой? Не `varchar` ли?

Comment: @u_mulder, VARCHAR

Comment: Ну прекрасно. Строки сортируются иначе чем числа.

Comment: Видимо crossbar у вас строка, а не число. поэтому min/max работают с ней как со строками (строка считается больше, если у нее больше первый символ). Если вы уверены, что кроме цифр там ничего не содержится то у вас два пути: сделать колонку правильного типа (int например), или в функциях приводить явно к числу в виде `max(crossbar+0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учетом того что у Вас `crossbar` имеет тип `VARCHAR` для него функции `MIN()` и `MAX()` работают немного по-другому. Для строк максимальным элементом выбирается та строка, у которой символы больше чем у других. Т.е. строка `64` будет больше чем `526`, потому что первый символ строки - `6` больше чем первый символ другой строки - `5`. Подробнее о `MIN()` и `MAX()` можно прочитать [здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp).